# How to share classes between different apps in a nestjs monorepo?

Tags: nestjs, monorepo

I have this piece of structure in my nestjs monorepo:

```
apps
|-project1
  |-src
    |-admin
      |-dtos (class 1, class2... index.ts)
|-project2
  |-src
    |-user
      |-class 3 (import {class1} from 'xxx'
```

Attempt 1 - I let it auto import and xxx be like: "@apps/project1/src/admin/dtos".
Attempt 2 - I using relative path and xxx be like: "../../../project1/src/admin/dtos".
Both attemps failed because when I build the two projects, the project 2 built contains like:

```
dist
|-project1
|-project2 
  |-project1
  |-project2
```

And the projects can not start because the terminal says: "Can not find module xxx in project1".
How can I resolve this one. I have tried to search a lot but seems like I can not solve it. FYI: I am using nestjs cli to create monorepo. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Nest CLI](https://docs.nestjs.com/cli/libraries) to create a library (for this example I use the prefix *libs* when prompted by the command below):

```
nest g library my-library
```

The files

- index.ts
- my-library.module.ts
- my-library.service.ts

will be generated in *libs/my-library/src*. You just need to keep *index.ts* in this directory and remove the other files.

Afterwards you can create files for your classes in libs/my-library/src, for example:

```js
export class MyOwnDTO {}
```

Then you need to add an export to your *index.ts* in your *libs/my-library/src*:

```js
export { MyOwnDTO } from './myown.dto';
```

After doing this you can import your DTO in your apps like this:

```js
import { MyOwnDTO } from "libs/my-library";
```